# tableview doesn't show anything?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made sure that my cell identifier was correct I'm not too sure what the problem is. I've been rereading the code on this viewController and I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if there's a specific reason why my tableview isn't loading.

```swift
import UIKit
import JGProgressHUD

class BasketViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //MARK: TO DO CHECK IF USER IS LOGGED IN
        loadBasketFromFirestore()
    }

    //MARK: VARS
    var basket : basket?
    var allItems : [Item] = []
    var purchaseItemID : [String] = [] //holds id of items you want to purchase
    var hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)

    //MARK: IBOUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalItemsInBasket: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkOutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var footerView: UIView!

    //MARK: IBACTIONS
    @IBAction func checkOutButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {}

//something is wrong with

    //MARK: DOWNLOAD BASKET
    private func loadBasketFromFirestore(){
        //MARK: CHANGE 1234 TO A USER ID STRING
        downloadBasketFromFirestore("1234") { (basket) in
            self.basket = basket
            self.getBasketItems()
        }
    }

    private func getBasketItems(){
        if (basket != nil) {
            print("getting items")
            downloadItems(_withIDS: basket!.itemID) { (allItems) in
                self.allItems = allItems
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else { print("basket is nil")}
    }
}

extension BasketViewController : UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basketCell", for: indexPath) as! ITEMTableViewCell
        cell.generateCellForITEMS(item: allItems[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the delegate and dataSource.

Comment: I did in the extension

Comment: No, you are confirming to protocols. have you set tableView.delegate = your_VC programatically or you can set delegate and datasource in storyboard.

Comment: how can I do that programmatically and or threw storyboard

Comment: Below `super.viewDidLoad()` add `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: thank you so much that fixed it I Appreciate everyones help